# Time based Events JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

I've developped a live-tracking website for my school, where you have two fullscreen graphs, G1 and G2. I want to display G1 for 10 minutes before displaying G2 for 2minutes. So I guessed i could do it as follows:
(Do not take syntax into account)

```
hideG1(){ //the same as displayG2
    G1.hide();
    G2.display();
    setTimeout(hideG2, 10minutes);
}

hideG2(){ //the same as displayG2
    G2.hide();
    G1.display();
    setTimeout(hideG1, 2minutes);
}
```

However as setTimeout gets executed instantly it fills the stack, giving me an error, thus inhibiting the rest of the code to be executed.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: It isn't fully understood what is the problem. This should work. Can you add more real code?

Comment: 2 minutes would be `setTimeout(hideG1, 2 * 60 * 1000)`.  The time for `setTimeout` is in milliseconds.  `2minutes` is not a valid time value or a valid variable name.

Comment: are 10minutes and 2minutes supposed to be variables?  Try converting ms to the minute timeframes.

Comment: You are trying to call `hideG2` before it has been declared.

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/fwhd1ube/

Comment: I am assuming you are using the jQuery framework based on .hide(). You need to replace .display() with .show().

Comment: I told you to not take into account the syntax ^^ I'm using words instad of real code just to show the problem. However as I said, the functions work, and it doesn't matter how I call them, they are treated as declared, but they fill the stack while calling each other.

Answer (score 2):

`2minutes` is not a valid time value or a valid variable name as Javascript identifiers cannot start with a number and the time must be specified in milliseconds.

A timeout to run in 2 minutes would be

```
setTimeout(hideG1, 2 * 60 * 1000);
```

The time for `setTimeout` is in milliseconds.

---

It also isn't clear what you mean by `.display()`.  If you intend for that to be the opposite of `.hide()` in jQuery, then it should be `.show()`.  So, assuming that `G1` and `G2` are jQuery objects, then you could have this:

```
function hideG1(){
    G1.hide();
    G2.show();
    setTimeout(hideG2, 10 * 60 * 1000);    // 10 minutes
};

function hideG2(){
    G2.hide();
    G1.show();
    setTimeout(hideG1, 2 * 60 * 1000);    // 2 minutes
};
```